# Iterator invalidation in while loops vs for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, while-loop, iterator

How are iterator invalidation treated in while vs for loops?

For example this code doesn't work because the iterators are invalidated after the insert:

```
    vector <int> v = {1,5,5,5,5,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    vector<int> :: iterator iter = v.begin();
    vector <int> :: iterator mid = v.begin() + (v.end()-v.begin())/2;

    while(iter != mid){
        if(*iter == 5){
            iter = v.insert(iter, 0);
            iter++;
        }
        iter++;
    }
```

However if i replace the while loop with this for loop it compiles and runs properly:

```
   for(auto curr = iter; curr != mid; ++curr){
        if(*iter == 5){
            iter = v.insert(iter, 0);
            iter++;
        }
        iter++;
    }
```

Why does the for loop work and the while loop not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The both loops are incorrect because after inserting an element in the vector the iterator mid becomes invalid. The memory allocated for elements of the vector can be reallocated.

To achieve what you are trying  to do it is better to introduce a count of iterations as for example

```
auto n = v.size() / 2;

for ( auto iter = v.begin(); n != 0; n-- )
{
    if( *iter == 5 )
    {
        iter = v.insert(iter, 0);
        iter++;
    }
    iter++;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector <int> v = { 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto n = v.size() / 2;

    for ( auto it = v.begin(); n != 0; n-- )
    {
        if ( *it == 5 )
        {
            it = v.insert( it, 0 );
            ++it;
        }

        ++it;
    }

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 5 5 5 5 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 0 5 0 5 0 5 0 5 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Or the loop can look like

```
for ( auto it = v.begin(); n--; ++it )
{
    if ( *it == 5 )
    {
        it = v.insert( it, 0 );
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i also expected both of them to not work, but after testing the one with the for loop it actually runs. That's why i'm confused.

Comment: @CTH You are using an invalidated iterator so you have undefined behavior - anything can happen - you can even get the appearance of a working program.

Comment: ahhh i see. Thanks for the help and clarification guys.